# jQuery animation on click do something else than first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to replicate the [www.winston.com](http://www.winston.com) homepage animation (that with the circles).
But so far I only managed to do [THIS ( LINK HERE )](http://jsfiddle.net/valacheeduard/fMPqF/) . How should I continue so when i`ll press now on those triangles, some text to appear and disappear according to the information.

I`d appreciate your help.

My jQuery code looks this way:

```
$("#green-circle").click(function () {
$("#green-circle").animate({
    width: "120",
    height: "120",
    marginTop: "20",
    marginLeft: "0"
}, 2000, "linear", function () {
    $(this).after("");
}),
$("#blue-circle").animate({
    width: "120",
    height: "120",
    marginTop: "20",
    marginLeft: "5"
}, 2000, "linear", function () {
    $(this).after("");
}),
$("#green-circle2").animate({
    width: "120",
    height: "120",
    marginTop: "20",
    marginLeft: "5"
}, 2000, "linear", function () {
    $(this).after("");
});
```

});

[HERE IS MY jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/valacheeduard/fMPqF/) and [HERE IS THE WEBSITE EXAMPLE](http://www.winston.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need JQuery `.one()` function :

### http://api.jquery.com/one/

This will allow a function to only be run once.

So what you can do is use the `.one()` function initially and add a new class or id to the elements, and then have a new function that will run off of the new class that was just added.

This will allow you to use 2 different functions, one for the start and then one afterwards.